# How convert Angular promise to jquery deferred object

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise, jquery-deferred, angular-promise

I want to return promises from my module/sdk to non-angular javascript. For example if I'm returning promise to a jquery, I should be probably sending jquery deferred object. How can I convert an Angular promise to a jquery promise/deferred obj.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Why?  Have an example?

Comment: For example you can convert any third party promise to a $q/Q promise using $q.when(thirdPartyPromise). But should have that library to use my promise. I do not want to force my client to use Q or angular so that he can reuse my promise. If I could convert it to the compatible promise he wanted it would be less pain to use.

Comment: You should consider using a minimalist promise library and not jQuery promises, jQuery promises are inherently problematic in error handling.

Comment: @phani Promises are [designed to be interchangeable](https://promisesaplus.com/) between implementations, you're not forcing your client to anything. jQuery deferreds don't comform to the Promise spec, so you shouldn't use them outside of jQuery.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>**Disclaimer**: jQuery promises don't play nice with other libraries - at *all*. jQuery will not assimilate other third party promises on its own. Angular $q promises on the other hand - will, so whenever you have the choice, assimilate the jQuery promise into an Angular promise and not vice versa. (All this changes in jQuery 3.0, if you see this disclaimer and 3.0 has already been released - please leave a comment).</strike>

Converting a jQuery promise into an Angular promise:

```
var angularPromise = $q.when(jQueryPromise); // eg: $q.when($.get(...));
```

Converting a jQuery promise to a native or Bluebird promise:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve(jQueryPromise); // eg: Promise.resolve($.get(..));
```

Converting a Promises/A+ complaint promise like $q Angular promise or Bluebird promise or native promises into jQuery promises:

```
function convert(p){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    p.then(function(val){
       d.resolve(val);
    }, function(err){ 
       d.reject(err); 
    });
    return d.promise();
}

var jqPromise = convert($http.get(...)); // example usage

// you might be tempted to think you can easily do:
var jqPromise = $.when($http.get(...));
// however - this will will fail inconsistently due to differences between 
// jQuery and Angular promises
```

Also worth noting - **Angular promises can consume jQuery promises**:

```
$http.get(...).then(function(id){
    return $.get("http://..."+id); // will work, though pointless because $http.get
}).then(function(result){
     // contains result of $.get call here
});
```

Comment: hello, I have a signalR promise (SignalR returns a Jquery promise), chunkPromise=proxy.server.myMethod(a,b)
but when I do $q.when(chunkPromise) the returned object is "d", with only a $$state member, and not a $q promise. what do I do wrong?

Comment: Jquery 3.0 has been released ;)

Comment: Thanks @MarioLevrero!