# JQueryPromise to Promise - how to convert?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

I have a piece of code that returns a JQuery promise:

```
const jqProm = server.downloadAsync();
```

I wish to use it inside async function. I was hoping I could create something like C# *TaskCompletionSource*, return dummy *Task (Promise)* and as a handler for *jqProm* resolve/reject set the status of dummy *Task (Promise)*.

How to do that? I can find only *Promise* constructor that takes in resolver and rejector actions - but there is no thing like *PromiseCompletionSource*.

Comment: in the world of javascript Promise/A+ ... what is a `PromiseCompletionSource`

Comment: C#-think will only serve to confuse. jQuery 3+, do nothing, promises are already Promises/A+ compliant. jQuery <3 or if you need sugar methods of native/other promise, then `let promise = Promise.resolve(jQueryPromise)`.

Comment: The `resolve` and `reject` *resolver functions* **are** the JS equivalent of a `PromiseCompletionSource`. But I'm not sure what you need this for?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery promises are [*thenables*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435262/1048572), which means that you can use them with native promises just fine. They will implicitly get [`Promise.resolve`d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve). All you need to write is

```
await server.downloadAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've personally run into that matter today. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611078/how-convert-angular-promise-to-jquery-deferred-object) should do the trick.

Converting a jQuery promise into an Angular promise:

```
var angularPromise = $q.when(jQueryPromise); // eg: $q.when($.get(...));
```

Converting a jQuery promise to a native or Bluebird promise:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve(jQueryPromise); // eg: Promise.resolve($.get(..));
```